# Rust executable on raspberry pi failes to read oom_kill

Tags: ubuntu, rust, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, systemd

I compiled a rust program with the target architecture `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` to install and run it on a raspberry pi 3 with the systemarchitecture:

`Linux ubuntu 5.11.0-1009-raspi #10-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri May 14 14:49:24 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`.

If I try to start it via the bash (`$ <executable>`) it starts without an error.

However when trying to start it via a systemd service looking like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Client
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=<path-to-exec>
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get the following error (via `systemctl status <service>`):

```
Aug 01 11:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: service: Job 19631607 service/start finished, result=done
Aug 01 11:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Client.
Aug 01 11:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: service: Failed to read oom_kill field of memory.events cgroup attribute: No such file or directory
Aug 01 11:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: service: Child 874846 belongs to service.
Aug 01 11:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 01 11:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 01 11:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: service: Service will restart (restart setting)
Aug 01 11:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: service: Changed running -> failed
Aug 01 11:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: service: Unit entered failed state.
```

Comment: Did you put the full absolute path in `ExecPath`? And is your executable in your home folder or in a global location?

Comment: Yes the path is absolute. The file is located in the directory `/usr/local/sbin`.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259028

Comment: I can't find the connection between the question asked and the link you provided @SvetlinZarev